# text processing: find multiple words split by newline

Tags: regex, replace, sed

How do find multiple words that might be split by newlines, without removing the newlines?

E.g.

```
The promotion and merchandise aided the success of We Are
the World and raised over $63 million for humanitarian
aid in Africa and the US.
```

Use sed (or any *nix text processing tool, e.g. awk, perl) to search for `We Are the World` and replace it with e.g. `<song title>` so it appears as:

```
The promotion and merchandise aided the success of <song title>
and raised over $63 million for humanitarian
aid in Africa and the US.
```

I have a bunch of search patterns (song titles) that I want to search pieces of text for and replace all of them with `<song title>`. I do not want to remove the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { gsub(/ +/,"[[:space:]]+",old); old = tolower(old) }
{ tail = tail $0 RS }
END {
    head = ""
    while ( match(tolower(tail),old) ) {
        trgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) new
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        if (trgt ~ RS) {
            head = head RS
            sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"",tail)
        }
    }
    printf "%s%s", head, tail
}

$ awk -v old='we are the world' -v new='<song title>' -f tst.awk file
The promotion and merchandise aided the success of <song title>
and raised over $63 million for humanitarian
aid in Africa and the US.
```

The above assumes your requirement for handling newlines within the old song title is to append that newline to the end of the new song title and remove any blank chars that followed the old song title.

Comment: You might want to test it with some other variations of your input and see if you have any different requirements that need to be handled, e.g. multiple newlines within the old song name, the old song name containing a newline but being followed by punctuation instead of a space. etc., etc. What if the old song name was a common word or phrase like "Pure" - how would you know if you're replacing a song name or just a word "The song Pure by Lightning Seed is good. Pure artistry!". I made all my tests case-insensitive - maybe that's not what you want but I think you need it.

Comment: You are right, in generic cases this should be kept in mind. In my case the "songs" are all unique strings, and will not appear as regular text. And yes, case-insensitive was not requested, but is indeed useful.